# Calling Action in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

as a newbie to Razor Pages I have a question regarding calling methods from Razor Page.

- The method `SubtractProduct()` is defined in my domain model.
- The Index Page has `IActionResult sellProduct()` that calls `subtractProduct()` for a specified ProductId.

But I have no clue how to call this method on my html page.
I've tried a lot of combinations, but nothing seems to be working. Anyone knows how to deal with this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

My domain model is:

```
public class Product

{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }   
    ...
    public void SubtractProduct()
    {
        Quantity -= 1;
    }
}
```

My Index Page code is:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly CfEshop.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public IndexModel(CfEshop.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<Models.Product> Product { get;set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Product = await _context.Products
            .Include(p => p.Categories).ToListAsync();
    }

    public IActionResult sellProduct(int id)
    {
        var products = _context.Products;

        _context.Products.Find(id).SubtractProduct();
        return Page();
    }
}
```

And finaly my Razor page:

```
@page
@model CfEshop.Pages.Product.IndexModel
<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product[0].Quantity)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Product)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-page-handler="SellProduct" asp-route="@item.ProductId">Sell Product</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Razor pages have `handler-methods` which are HTTP verbs. So to call a method from your page you need to put `On` followed by `the http verb you want` then your `method name`.

E.g.:

```cs
public IActionResult OnGetSellProduct(int id)
{
   var products = _context.Products;

   _context.Products.Find(id).SubtractProduct();
   return Page();
}
```

And in your view pass the name to the `asp-page-handler` without the `OnPost or OnGet` prefix or `Async` suffix.

Edit: here is the view sample:

```html
<a 
    asp-page-handler="SellProduct" 
    asp-route-id="@item.ProductId">Sell Product</a>
```

#### For more information check out

- [Introduction to Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).
- [Razor Pages Handler Methods](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods).

Comment: After I changed my view to
<a asp-page="./Index" asp-page-handler="SellProduct" asp-route="@item.ProductId">Sell Product</a>

I get this error:

InvalidOperationException: Cannot determine the 'href' attribute for <a>. The following attributes are mutually exclusive:
asp-route
asp-controller, asp-action
asp-page, asp-page-handler
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.AnchorTagHelper.Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)

Comment: your <a> should be something like this: <a asp-page-handler="SellProduct" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId">Sell Product</a>, you need to add `asp-route-id` to match the argument in your action `id`.

Comment: I added the view sample to the answer. Please try it out.

Comment: Thanks It works - My method is now:
      public async  Task OnGetSellProductAsync(int id)
        {
            _context.Products.Find(id).SubtractProduct();
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            Product = await _context.Products
                .Include(p => p.Categories).ToListAsync();
        }
But now Im facing another issue - whenever I press F5 after calling this method my Quantity is subtracted again :). 
In my URL there is https://localhost:44321/Product?id=55&handler=SellProduct

Is there any way to reset this? Like action redirect or something?

Comment: You can use `return RedirectToPage();` to return to the current page. Usually altering the database or values should be through a Post HTTP verb by submitting a form.

Comment: I reworked my solution to work as you inteded - by submitting  a form. It is way better than what I had in mind. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that :D.

Answer (score 0):

add the below `tagHelper` and user asp-action="`@Model.ReturnUrl`" to resolve the `url` of Calling Action in Razor Pages

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```