# How to link anchor tag to c# function?

Tags: c#, html, razor

i want to link an  tag to a c# function on the backend side. I tried looking up on the internet but im not getting very far.
Here is what I have so far:

```
<a asp-page="/Notifications" runat="server" onserverclick="RemoveCount" ><h5 class="font-italic text-left">Notifications </h5></a>
```

And this is the function in the backend which im trying to link

```
public void RemoveCount(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var cs = Database.Database.Connector();
            using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();

            var sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE counter ";
            using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Don't you want something like an [`ActionLink`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709001/html-actionlink-vs-url-action-in-asp-net-razor)?

Comment: Is it razor pages app? If yes then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53895231/2501279) should help you.

Comment: @anonD, do you use blazor?